# Can't retrieve and use a DocumentReference field in a Firebase function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I won't include code here because I've tried so many things that didn't work that I wouldn't know which one to quote.

I am trying to write a Firestore cloud function using TypeScript that will detect when a Firestore document is created using .onCreate(), retrieve the reference field for the creator of that document, and then use that reference to update a field in the creator's user record. Basically, I want a field for the user that keeps a tally of how many documents they have created in a certain collection. I know there is probably a more direct way to do this, but please humor me.  I have other ways I would like to use this as well.  I've been trying to debug, and when I get data from the reference field, it seems to get identified simply as [object Object].  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you share - screenshot of documents from both collections and screenshot of that [object Object] thing (and what logs it would be still helpful)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a couple more hours of searching, I finally found out that you need to apply .path to the end of the reference.  That was super easy.  I wish it had been easier to find!

Comment: How did you define your typescript interface so you can call the .path function?